# exclude link from mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

hello this is my htaccess code

```
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lang/

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.rss|\.atom|\.txt)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
```

i have this contact form

http://www.example.com/lang/contact-se

when user use the form and contact

it redirect to

http://www.example.com/lang/contact-se.html

and give me error page not found

how can i exclude this link only from rewrite and redirect to .html

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to submit to `/lang/contact-se` instead of `/lang/contact-se.html`.

Not sure what this has to do with your rules, both contact-se and contact-se.html gets pointed to `index.php`.

Comment: This Is A Vivvo Cms Thanks for your reply i fixed the problem thanks so much